# How to convert Date/Time Serial to Seconds using Boost Library

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I am trying to convert a date/Time in double format (eg 147368.9063 = "6/24/2303  9:45:00 PM") to seconds, the sample converted using excel, I would like to repeat this in c++ with the Boost Library.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far ? show your code ?

Comment: Just create a duration from the double, and add it to a base date of 12/30/1899.